# Getting Error while deploying the glass mirror API java starter on public tomcat server

Tags: java, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have deployed the war file of starter project with some small modification in index.jsp and MainServlet.java. Now when I am hitting the server I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.generateSessionId(ManagerBase.java:805)
    org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.createSession(ManagerBase.java:651)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2300)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:897)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:909)
    com.google.glassware.AuthUtil.getUserId(AuthUtil.java:82)
    com.google.glassware.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:55)
```

Hi have changed the redirect URI also to my server one. Please suggest some changes that can be done to get rid of the error.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the modifications you made? This error is typically associated with trying to manage the session in a non-standard way. See https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54315 for example.

Comment: Changed the war file to ROOT.war works for me. and on the Server there are not write permissions given to me. write now I am getting the index.jsp working on public server.